# python if-condition inside simple arithmetic

Tags: python

first one makes sense, but the second one should be `2`, shouldnot it?

```
>>> 1 + 3 if 2>1 else 1
4
>>> 1 + 3 if 2>3 else 1
1
```

whereas,

```
>>> r = 3 if 2>3 else 1
>>> r
1
```

why is it behaving differently, or am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

I thought

```
1 + "3 if 2>3 else 1"
```

will be either `1 + 3` or `1 + 1` depending on `if`

Comment: In what way is it different?

Comment: the precedence I guess.

Comment: What is the logic in this question I still don't get it. Basically you are asking parantheses works. If you have trouble with using parantheses in arithmetic, then your question is unclear what you asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second one would only give 2 if you would set the parentheses as follows

```
1 + (3 if 2>3 else 1)
```

Your statement is equivalent to

```
(1 + 3) if 2>3 else 1
```

Thus giving you 1

Comment: oh thank you, this was messing me up.